# What does it mean when one talks about splitting field of a multivariable polynomial? And then, Galois group of that splitting field?

Tags: galois-theory, splitting-field, galois-extensions

I came across the following, while I was reading a recent research article. I do not know how to interpret it; the article does not define this concept (perhaps because it is too elementary). Could anyone possibly help me or point me in an appropriate direction? The article reads:

Let $F(x,y)$ be an irreducible integral binary cubic form having splitting field with Galois group $S_{3}$?

In my basic Galois theory class, we never considered splitting field of a polynomial in two variables. Since there are two variables, splitting field is an extension of what field? Rationals?

Comment: Sure.. but is that really what the paper is talking about.. why not $F(1, y)$? or $F(x, a)$ for some integer $a$? or $F(a, y)$? Do all of these have same Galois group (when splitting field's galois group is taken)? @quasi

Comment: Since the form is homogeneous, it splits in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ into a product of linear forms. The splitting field is the smallest field containing the coefficients of the linear factors.

Comment: @quasi Ohh.. Then we attach all the roots of the form $F(x,y)$ that are in $F(x, 1)$, then consider the extension and then the Galois group? 
Secondly, Would you happen to know of any reference where some concrete examples and perhaps some other results on Galois theory of binary forms are given?

I asked because how do I know if such a form with Galois group $S_{3}$ or some other well-known group even exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example . . .

Let $F(x,y)=x^3-2y^3$, and let $f(x)=F(x,1)=x^3-2$.

Then letting $a,b,c$ denote the roots of $f$, we get
$$
F(x,y)
=
y^3f\Bigl({\small{\frac{x}{y}}}\Bigr)
=
y^3
\Bigl({\small{\frac{x}{y}}}-a\Bigr)
\Bigl({\small{\frac{x}{y}}}-b\Bigr)
\Bigl({\small{\frac{x}{y}}}-c\Bigr)
=
(x-ay)(x-by)(x-cy)
$$
so the splitting field of $F$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{Q}(a,b,c)$, which is the same as the splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Since $[\mathbb{Q}(a,b,c):\mathbb{Q}]=6$, the Galois group of $f$ is $S_3$.

Comment: Thanks for your kind support and response. I am very grateful. Last question: the reason my Galois group has to fix $f(x)$ is because $F(x,y)$ is actually a polynomial with coefficient in $F(x,1)$ and hence has to fix the terms with $x$ in the linear factors, right?

Comment: Since $F$ and $f$ have the same splitting field over $\mathbb{Q}$, they have the same Galois group.

Comment: Yep.. the homogenization and de-homogenization acting as a bridge between two..

Comment: I apologize for this extra question (please don't report me for this).. Makes me wonder, what happens when polynomial is not homogeneous... Fundamentally, what is the obstruction?

Comment: A non-constant bivariate homogeneous polynomial $F(x,y)\in\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ splits completely into a product of linear factors. On the other hand, as an example, the polynomial $F(x,y)=x^2+y^2+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$.